# C# socket connecting in VPN

Tags: c#, sockets, vpn

I have a cisco VPN client on my home computer, that is intended to be used to connect to my workplace computer
There are 2 groups in VPN client: secured routes and local routes
Workplace computer's ip is in secured ones, local routes group is empty
I need to create a simple sockets app that connects from my home computer to the one in my office
The very first line in my code

```
Dns.GetHostName(myWorkIp)
```

throws an exception "Host not available"

Answer (score 0):

It means the dns server doesn't know a name for that ip address, it has no effect on whether you can connect to it with a socket or not. So just try to connect.